# VirtualBox for windows 8 64Bits

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to run Virtual Box on Host windows 8 64 Bits but it is nit showing 64 Bits option. I have tried to update my BIOS and found that Virtualization is enabled but my processor does not support VT-x. Is there another way to run VirtualBox on it.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox requires Intel's VT-x (or AMD's AMD-v) to be able to host 64-bit guests.

[Source](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=62339)

Look up your processor with the manufacturer, and if it *does* support VT-x, ensure you have no other hypervisors loaded/running (ie: Hyper-v) that may be hogging the VT-x, making it unavailable to VirtualBox.

Comment: thanks. I have actually checked my processor and found out that it does not support VT-x and hypervisor is not running. is there any way out. My laptop is Dell Inspiron N5040, P6200 Intel Pentium (R).